# Django Class based view post data to ListView?

Tags: listview, post, formview, django-class-based-views, django-1.5

I have a form with 2 fields(start Date, End Date), i want to post data to ListView following is my code it is working, but i want to know this is the right way to do the post method in django 1.5 class based views. It is possible to write GET & POST method in same ListView, where in get method will return ListView & in post method will return Filtered ListView & render data in same template.

froms.py

```
class DailytaskfilterForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DailytaskfilterForm, self).clean()

        try:
            start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        except:
            start_date = ""

        if not start_date:
            errormsg = "Please Select start Date"
            self._errors["start_date"] = self.error_class([errormsg])

        try:
            end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        except:
            end_date = ""

        if not end_date:
            errormsg = "Please Select End Date"
            self._errors["end_date"] = self.error_class([errormsg])

        return cleaned_data
```

Views.py

```
class DailytaskfilterformView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    template_name = 'viewdailytask.html'
    form_class = DailytaskfilterForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        sdate = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        edate = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard:dailytask-list-filter', kwargs={'start_date':sdate, 'end_date':edate}))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

class Dailytaskfilterview(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    template_name = 'viewdailytask.html'
    model = DailyTask
    context_object_name = 'dailytasks'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Dailytaskfilterview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        name = User.objects.get(username=user)
        fullname = "%s %s" % (name.first_name, name.last_name)
        context['fname'] = fullname
        context['pk'] = name.pk
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date = self.kwargs['start_date']
        end_date = self.kwargs['end_date']
        user = self.request.user
        pk = User.objects.get(username=user).id
        return DailyTask.objects.filter(user=pk).filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date)).order_by('-date')
```

urls.py

```
url(
    regex=r'dailytask/filter/$',
    view=DailytaskfilterformView.as_view(),
    name='dailytask-filter'
    ),

url(
    regex=r'dailytask/filter/(?P<start_date>[-\w\d]+)/(?P<end_date>[-\w\d]+)/$',
    view=Dailytaskfilterview.as_view(),
    name='dailytask-list-filter'
    ),
```

Comment: Uh sorry, but why would you want to POST to a `ListView`? This view is for displaying things, and all display views should be called by a GET, because POST is for additions and changes. If you want to do a search or filter on a list, GET makes much more sense than POST, as the link then can be passed around and the like.

If your filter is really very complex and with a lot of items, it might make sense to turn it into a separate model which could then be stored and referred by something like `/items/?filter=235`.

Comment: @BerislavLopac if i write get then it will work but, how should i validate my form using django forms. & if i use get method i have to follow the same code just instead of post method i'll use get. My question, is there any other way to do this task, instead of post data to another view as i have done please check my views.py.

Comment: You don't need to validate the code if you're just filtering and not actually changing the values in the database. But you can always force any validation you need in the `get_queryset` method before querying.